# Next 13 multiple root layouts Causing Page to go blank with not-found error

Tags: next.js, routes

I am attempting to add multiple root layouts to my existing Next 13 web application like this:

```
app
-- (general)/                   
         /signin/page.js
         /singout/page.js
         /singup/page.js
         /layout.js

-- (admin)/
          /page.js
          /layout.js
```

However, when I start my application, all I get is a blank screen with a not-found error in my VScode terminal. I deleted the next folder and run `npm install` again but its still the same result. I also realised that the route grouping also affected the path to some files and components. Has anyone face this issue and how did you solve it.